# sfdx RunSpecifiedTests

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx

new to salesforce and trying to build an `sfdx` pipeline using Azure Devops. One of my requirements is to `RunSpecifiedTests` when deploying. I've got the pipeline running with `-RunLocaltest` successfully but having difficulties following guides to do the RunSpecifiedTests.

My question is,

Where are these test files go? do they go into the same `./manifest/Package.xml?` or straight into `force-app/classes?`

script: `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -p "./manifest/TestA.cls-meta.xml" RunSpecifiedTests --runtests TestA -c -d ./toDeploy -u devOrg -w 10`

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the metadata API (mdapi) format, test classes go in to the `classes` folder, along with your Apex code. If you move to "source" format, you can store your test classes in their own folders, such as `force-app/main/default/classes` and `force-app/test/default/classes`, or some other design of your choice. Note that in the mdapi format, you should deploy the entire folder, not a specific file (e.g. `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d manifest/`).

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help @sfdcox, I've now added the sample two test classes in the "classeses" ,  but I am still getting some errors while running the pipeline. 
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TestA,TestB -c -d ./toDeploy -u devOrg -w 
2021-08-10T07:56:54.0538937Z TestA  test1

2021-08-10T07:56:54.0540204Z TestB  test20
2021-08-10T07:56:54.0542043Z TestB  test30
2021-08-10T07:56:54.5913925Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2021-08-10T07:56:54.5944994Z ##[section]Finishing: Run validation on source code

Comment: @ITInfinity You'll have to check the logs to see what's going on. They should be in `~/.sfdx/`